# How to load dataset file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am learning to use Neural Network Toolbox to classify the images as part of my assignment. I am trying to understand Crab Classification in MATLAB. How is the crab dataset loaded in various vectors?

[image: Crab Dataset in MATLAB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is more than one way to read data into MATLAB from a file. The simplest, though least flexible, procedure is to use the load command to read the entire contents of the file in a single step. The load command requires that the data in the file be organized into a rectangular array. No column titles are permitted. One useful form of the load command is

```
load name.ext
```

this [article](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/plotting/loadingPlotData.html) may help you